# How to prove the uniqueness of complement in the algebra of sets ( without using set theory but exclusively the laws of boolean algebra )?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

[edited]

In abstract algebra, the uniqueness of inverse in a group  is proved using more basic laws ( laws of groups themselves, not extraneous laws). Could the same thing be done regarding the algebra of sets?

How to prove, using only the laws of the algebra of sets, that a set has only one complement?

Am I wrong in assuming that complement uniqueness can be proved inside the system of the algebra of sets?

Is it rather a postulate?

Comment: With what you gave as definition(?) of complement, the complement is *not* unique. Namely, $A\cap B=\emptyset=A\cap C$ does *not* imply $B=C$. Just think of $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $C=\{3\}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Post edited in order to take your comment into account.

Comment: What are you calling "the laws of the algebra of sets" ?

Comment: @CaptainLama. My reference is : <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra>

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Thanks for showing the mistake the original post contained.

Comment: In a "naive" approach, you have to use a "universe" $U$ and $A^C := U \setminus A$. Thus $x \in A^C \text {  iff  } x \in U \text {  and  } x \notin A$. Assume thus that there are two "complements" ($A_1$ and $A_2$) of $A$ in $U$ and that they are different, i.e. $z \in A_1$ and $z \notin A_2$ for some $z$. Now apply the def of complement and find a cotradiction.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza.So the proof requires logic. I mean: the proposition cannot be proved using simply the algebra of sets laws?

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames I've don't think I've ever heard of a proof that doesn't require logic.

Comment: The proof requires the definition of complement (and this is set theory). **Every** proof requires the rules of logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set in a universal set $U$, and let $A_1$ be a complement for $A$. If $A_2$ is another complement for $A$, we have:

$A_1=U \cap A_1= (A\cup A_2) \cap A_1= (A\cap A_1) \cup (A_2\cap A_1)=A_2\cap A_1$.

Similarly, $A_2=U\cap A_2= (A\cup A_1)\cap A_2=(A\cap A_2)\cup (A_1\cap A_2)=A_1\cap A_2$.

Hence, $A_1=A_2\cap A_1= A_1 \cap A_2= A_2$.

This approach is very similar to showing uniqueness in abstract algebra.

Comment: I seee how it proves that if A1 and A2 are two complements of A, then A1= A1 Inter A2. Could you explain why A1 Inter A2 is finally equal to A2?

Comment: I mean, how to explain the  last step in this series of equalities?

Comment: We showed that $A_1=A_2 \cap A_1$ for $any$ two complements regardless of their order of appearance. Reverse the roles now, you’ll get $A_2=A_1\cap A_2$.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: @Miled. I agree that commutativity of intersection allows to change the order on the left side. Does  the fact that A1 and A2 are arbitrary also allows me substitute A2 for A1 on the right side? Isnt't this assuming what is to be proved?

Comment: I clarified the point adding an edit

Comment: @Miled. Thanks. I've just found at WikiProof  a genaral proof valid for all boolean algebras< https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complement_in_Boolean_Algebra_is_Unique>

Comment: That boolean proof is incidentally our approach here. You’re welcome

Answer (score 2):

If $$\tag1A\cap B=\emptyset\text{ and }A\cup B=U,$$ then 
$$x\in B\iff x\in U\land x\notin A $$
hence $B$ is uniquely determind by $U$ and $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Let it be that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are complements of set $A$ in universal set $X$.

Then for $i=1,2$: $$B_i\cup A=X\text{ and }B_i\cap A=\varnothing$$

If $x\in B_1$ then $x\notin A$ since $B_1\cap A=\varnothing$.

Next to that $x\in X=B_2\cup A$ so we conclude that $x\in B_2$.

Proved is now that $B_1\subseteq B_2$ and similarly it can be proved that $B_2\subseteq B_1$.

Our final result is then: $$B_1=B_2$$So complements are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Below a proof that can be found at WikiProof
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complement_in_Boolean_Algebra_is_Unique

[image]